# How to display MySQL timestamp in correct timezone with PHP / CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, codeigniter-4

I have a CodeIgniter 4 application that reads a timestamp from a MySQL database and I want it to be displayed in local timezone which is different from UTC, let's say Europe/Madrid (UTC+2 or UTC+1 depending on the summer time).

The problem is that my local server for testing is in Europe/Madrid (currently UTC+1) while my production server is in UTC and it is a shared hosting so I think I can't change its timezone.

So `select now()` returns different timezones, my local time in local environment but one hour less in production environment.

The problem is that when I read the timestamp from MySQL local server is returning it in UTC+1 while production server in UTC, and I want it to be displayed in UTC+1 always.

So, displaying directly `echo $mytimestamp` works in local server but gives wrong time in production.

The only solution I have found is to do something like this:

```
(new DateTime($mytimestamp, new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'))->format('d-m-Y H:i')
```

Perhaps the code can be simplified but that is basically creating a PHP DateTime assuming that it is in UTC and asking it to be changed to Europe/Madrid (UTC+1).

This way, correct time is displayed in production but now time is one hour ahead in localhost, which is not a big problem, but that makes me think that if the shared hosting suddenly changes from UTC to another (or if I migrate to another server) the time will be incorrect.

So, in few words, I have found a trick to display the timestamp from MySQL in the appropiate timezone but its good working depends on the server's time.

Is there a better solution to display the timestamp in my local time that takes into account the time of the server/MySQL?

Please take note that it is a shared hosting and `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Madrid'` doesn't work (not enough permissions), while changing it for the session `SET time_zone = 'Europe/Madrid'`gives a `#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Madrid'` error.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter4, edit the **\Config\App.php** and change the value of **$appTimezone** (default is UTC).

```
public string $appTimezone = 'Europe/Madrid';
```

You can echo this value at any time :

```
echo app_timezone();
```